# xlsx - Write inside known cell number. Can't assign value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, xlsx

I'm using the package xlsx and trying to write something in a loop.

If I write the cell number directly, like for example `G3`, it works fine, but obviously something like this can't work:

```
    const workbook = XLSX.readFile('test.ods');
    const sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;  
    const sheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
      (...)
    let i = `G${k+1}`;
//we got a match , write the scores in the cells
sheet[i] = {t: 's' /* type: string */, v: checkData[k].location_id };
```

Any ideas on how I can use dynamic values for the cell name?

Comment: Hello, Instead of a static cell value to write in I need to provide the value dynamically       sheet['G3'] = {t: 's' /* type: string */, v: 'test' }; VS  sheet[`G${(k+1)}`] = {t: 's' /* type: string */, v: 'test' };

Answer (score 1):

Every item of the `sheet` array is an object of

```
{
    t: 's', // (string) Or 'n' (num) / 'b' (bool) /'d' (date)
    v: 'someValue'
}
```

This is modifying the `sheet[i]` by using a simple assign operator to the cell object:

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

var workbook = XLSX.readFile('test.xlsx');
const sheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];

for (let k = 1 ; k < 4 ; k++) {
    let i = `A${k+1}`;    
    console.log("Before update:");
    console.log(sheet[i]);
    console.log("After update:");
    let cell = {
        t: 's',
        v: 'myScore' + k
    }
    sheet[i] = cell;
    console.log(sheet[i]);
}
```

For a given test.xlsx of:

```
      A
---------
1 | TRUE
1 | foo
1 | baz
```

The output will be:

```
Before update:
{ t: 'b', v: true }
After update:
{ t: 's', v: 'myScore1' }
Before update:
{ t: 's', v: 'foo' }
After update:
{ t: 's', v: 'myScore2' }
Before update:
{ t: 's', v: 'baz' }
After update:
{ t: 's', v: 'myScore3' }
```

You didn't mentioned in your code what is `checkData` array, but it does not matter, I just assume that it returns a `'myScore' + k`.